# The method is not applicable for the arguments(object)

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, jsp

this is my JSP page:

```
    function adding()
    {
        var text = "<br><br><br>" + 
                   "<form action='addEmployee' method='get'>" + 
                       "<tr>" + 
                           "<input  type='text' name='idEmployee' style='width: 20px;'>" +   
                           "<input type='text' name='CIN' style='width: 35px;'>" +  
                           "<input type='text' name='nom' style='width: 35px;'>" +
                           "<input type='text' name='prenom' style='width: 35px;'>" +
                           "<input type='text' name='e_mail' style='width: 35px;'>" +
                           "<input type='text' name='telephone' style='width: 35px;'>" + 
                           "<input type='text' name='fonction' style='width: 35px;'>" +
                           "<button type='submit'> Confirmer l'ajout </button>" + 
                       "</tr>" + 
                  "</form>"; 
       $(".liste").append(text);
}
```

I am recovering the fields in my servlet but getting an error: the method setCIN is not applicable for the arguments (Object) and this is the case for the other setters:

```
e.setCIN(Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("CIN")));
```

Comment: can you show all the error message. It seems not logical.

Comment: I put the script code in a comment and returned it, and there is no more error in the servlet. It is odd, but now the server is telling me that addEmployee is not available, is it because it is in a javascript code?

Comment: I tnink you have inconsistency in your WAR. I advise you to build it from zero and to try again.